# Google app engine performance impact in windows 8

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-8

I worked till today with eclipse and google app engine server and everything worked perfect and fast.
I've installed windows 8 today and when im performing database actions such as delete or put it is extremely slow.does anywone know what can be the cause of this?

thanks.

Comment: What language / SDK version do you use and do you use / installed the SQlite stub?

Comment: hey, not using sqlite stub. im using pydev with the latest gae SDK (installed today). any thoughts?

Comment: I also use pydev, but also sqlite. It boosts performance. From the docs : Description: If you store a lot of data in your datastore, you can improve performance and startup times by switching to SQLite as the backend for your local datastore stub.

Comment: the problem is, even the admin site works very slow, everything else works perfect, but just the datastore actions seem to be slow out of proportion.

Comment: Admin site of the SDK or the GAE admin site? I have no performance problems at this moment with the GAE admin consolse data viewer.

Comment: yeah the gae console... i guess something is really messed up here.

Comment: I've had some issues with GAE being slow recently which were entirely unrelated to what my code was doing.  Wait a day and retry.

Comment: but this is happenning locally here. do you mean it slow over the internet or locally? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried devappserver2? http://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/

Comment: Wow it seems to be working! please write it as an answer, ill do some testing and if it is good ill accept your answer. thanks a lot.

Comment: do you know if there's any way to use it in eclipse? currently eclipse doesnt able to use it as google app engine library.

Comment: nevermind, It works perfectly on eclipse, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out it was the backend which impact the performance, even in HelloWorld simple project the datastore performance is really bad. I let go the backend and use only frontend for now as the devappserver2 seems to be not stable at the moment.

an issue was opened for google:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8732&thanks=8732&ts=1359318724